# How to make iOS client synchronize craigslist-like data

Tags: ios, synchronization

I'm curious what would be the best approach for synchronizing data found on a website like craigslist where an API is not available.

Let's say you have already downloaded a set of posts.  When you want to update the posts, what is the best way to compare what you already have with what is there, and then determine which ones are new to download and which ones should be deleted because they no longer exist on the server?

Please note my question isn't specific to craigslist, as this is just an example.  I'm interested in general principles/techniques with specific regards to iOS.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).